# Exclusion Script for Journey Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, journeybuilder, exclusion-script

I'm new to scripts and need a bit of help.
We have 2 DEs; 'Leads' and 'Members'. The plan is to send emails via Journey Builder to contacts on 'Leads' DE but exclude those who have become members (these contacts will have 'member number' field populated on 'Members' DE once they've become members). What should the exclusion script look like?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have a column *SubscriberKey* containing the SubscriberKey. The expression of your exclusion script needs to evaluate to true if the subscriber should be excluded from the send.

If also non-members are part of the Members data extension and just don't have a *member number* populated, this should work:

```
Not Empty(Lookup("Members", "member number", "SubscriberKey", _subscriberKey))
```

Comment: Thank you, @MarkusSlabina The first one works; just had to change 'Empty' to 'Not Empty'. Thanks again.

Comment: You are welcome! Sorry for the mistake, I updated my answer.